# ASP.NET UpdatePanel Javascript Callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, callback

I came across this issue recently and thought it was really helpful. My question was, how would you call a piece of javascript after an updatepanel loads via AJAX in ASP.NET?

I needed to reinitialize a jQuery datepicker after the panel had loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(panelLoaded);

function panelLoaded(sender, args){

    // Your code here

}

</script>
```

Essentially this is creating an instance of the PageRequestManager which handles all the UpdatePanel loading. Then ties the panelLoaded function to the pageLoaded event.

I also found this article which explains this is much more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163413.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The linked solution did not work for me. I had to:

1. Add the following tag to my pages

   `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>`
2. Create a javascript file, move the initialization code to the javascript file, then add a `<ScriptReference Path="myfile.js">` in my `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager><Scripts>` section.

No external browser definition files. Works on VS Studio Express 2013 for Web on Windows 7 Enterprise and on 2 live Windows 2003 Servers.