# Calling a jQuery Function Even in PostBacks in Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, postback

Consider that I have an ASP.NET page with a Button.
When I click the button, I want to execute a jquery script **after** the postback completes (not before).

I want to do this only with ASP.NET and jQuery.

`RegisterStartupScript` just works one time.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_pageLoaded(panelLoaded);

function panelLoaded(sender, args){

    // Your code here

}

</script>
```

You would be accessing the PageRequestManager object which allows you to execute code after a page or ajax update panel finishes loading. Refer to [ASP.NET UpdatePanel Javascript Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765650/asp-net-updatepanel-javascript-callback)

You could also try using the LiveQuery Plugin for jQuery, which monitors for ajax events and rebinds elements.

Comment: this code needs ScriptManager in Page.No way that we can do that without ScriptManager ?
thanks

Comment: The only other thing you could do is try the LiveQuery plugin for jQuery, which monitors for ajax events and rebinds after they complete. I haven't had the greatest luck using it with ASP.NET though.