# Date Picker Problem

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I started using Date Picker, and liked it very much. But now I am facing a problem with it. 
I have an ASP.Net application. I have a Master Page, and a Default.aspx page, and several user controls (.ascx pages). In one of those user controls, I have a GridView with textboxes containing dates. Those textboxes use datepickers. The GridView is in an UpdatePanel. I use custom paging for the GridView. When e.g. I need to go to the next page, that UpdatePanel is updated. The problem is that when I go from the initial page to another page, the date pickers disappear. 
Here is my code:
At the bottom of the master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.date").datepicker({ 
        showButtonPanel: true, 
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y', 
        changeYear: true, 
        closeText: 'X' 
    });
});
</script>
```

In the GridView:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWFHCDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("StrHCDate") %>' BorderStyle="None" Width="80%" CssClass="date" ></asp:TextBox>
```

The html generated for the initial GridView page:

```
<input id="ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPWorkflow_WorkflowGridView_ctl05_txtWFHCDate" class="date hasDatepicker" type="text" style="border-style:None;width:80%;" value="10/18/11" name="ctl00$CPHDefault$tcTPS$TPProd$ctl01$tcProduction$TPWorkflow$WorkflowGridView$ctl05$txtWFHCDate">
```

The html generated after changing GridView page:

```
<input id="ctl00_CPHDefault_tcTPS_TPProd_ctl01_tcProduction_TPWorkflow_WorkflowGridView_ctl05_txtWFHCDate" class="date" type="text" style="border-style:None;width:80%;" value="10/18/11" name="ctl00$CPHDefault$tcTPS$TPProd$ctl01$tcProduction$TPWorkflow$WorkflowGridView$ctl05$txtWFHCDate">
```

I tried to move the script from Master Page to the Default.aspx page, and to .ascx page, but nothing helps.

Could you please help?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think we are seeing the full picture here. "The problem is that when I go from the initial page to another page, the date pickers disappear." So is the JS on all those 3 pages? You need to initialize JS when a new page is loaded.

Comment: When I said "page" there, I didn't mean aspx page. I just meant custom paging of my GridView. E.g. by default the GridView displays first 100 records, when I press the Next button, the UpdatePanel is updated, and the GridView displays now next 100 records (the Date Pickers don't work anymore) and so on. The script is at the bottom of the Master Page, but I also tried the aspx page and the very ascx page (User control) where the GridView is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During page load, your ready() function calls datepicker() to add the necessary bindings to your text inputs.  When you change "pages" inside your GridView/UpdatePanel, those text inputs are discarded and replaced with new ones.

After the UpdatePanel loads the next "page", you need to call datepicker() again to re-bind the text inputs.  You might be able to integrate this into the .ascx control, or use the UpdatePanel callback described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765650/asp-net-updatepanel-javascript-callback).

Comment: Thanks, I used UpdatePanel callback, and it worked when I put it to the bottom of .aspx page. I wonder though why it didn't work at the bottom of Master page.